# Intranet to internet through a host that has 2 network interfaces, using the wireless one

Tags: linux, networking, routing, wifi

**Host_A**
eth0: 192.168.1.3
wlan0: 192.168.43.84

Both interfaces have internet access. eth0 through DSL router 192.168.1.1 and wlan0 through android access point, 192.168.43.1. The default gateway is 192.168.1.1, but I can easily switch it to the other one using the following commands as root:

```
ip route delete default
ip route add default via 192.168.43.1
```

Afterwards, Host_A uses the android access point to the internet successfully.

**Host_B**
eth0: 192.168.1.14

This goes to the internet through the DSL router 192.168.1.1. I want it go out through the wireless access point, which essentially means it should go through 192.168.1.3. To this end I did the following

```
ip route delete default
ip route add default via 192.168.1.3
```

Also I have enabled packet forwading in Host_A using:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Afterwards, cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward returns 1

The thing is, Host_B cannot got to the internet. I would like to have Host_B to have internet connectivity through Host_A wlan0 interface. Firewalls are disabled on both hosts and my conviction is that I should not have to mess with iptables to achieve this. Both hosts are Debian. Host_A and Host_B are on the same physical network using the DSL Router switching interface.

If anyone has any idea what could be wrong, I would be obliged.

[image: Before]
[image: Desired after]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable NAT in Host_A, telling it to route packets throutgh wlan0, this should do the trick:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: It did work, and I couldn't be happier it was so simple. Many thanks! Still I am kind at loss why NAT was required. Both DSL Router and the Android AP perform NAT. Since my hosts are in internal networks why is NAT on host_A required? I could not ask for such an answer here of course. A link to study something online if available would be great! @Fredi, many thanks again.

Comment: Glad it worked. As on why, i found this question / answer that seems well explained: http://superuser.com/questions/994647/does-iptables-as-a-router-always-require-masquerade-snat